# Aborted ssh -i command in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-ec2

I am running a shell script in which I am running two cross server scripts.
But script is failing below is the error:

below is the script:

```
#connector invoca loop

for file in "${invocaFiles[@]}"
do
        timestamp=$(echo ${file} | cut -d ':' -f1)
        file_path=$(echo ${file} | cut -d ':' -f2)
        echo -e "${timestamp}\t${file_path}" >> "${invoca_shell_output_file}"
done

aws s3 cp ${invoca_shell_output_file} ${s3_bucket}invoca_script/


**ksh /apps/dw/shell_scripts/run_ssh_ec2.sh "bash /apps/dw/etl/shell_scripts/ec2_script_change_log.sh"**


s3_ec2_sql="${S3_Bucket_name}ec2/sql/sql.txt"
s3_ec2_shell="${S3_Bucket_name}ec2/shell/shell.txt"
s3_ec2_con_sql="${S3_Bucket_name}ec2/con_sql/con_sql.txt"
s3_ec2_con_shell="${S3_Bucket_name}ec2/con_shell/con_shell.txt"
```

the highligted command is giving below error:

```
===>  END   REMOTE bash /apps/dw/etl/shell_scripts/ec2_script_change_log.sh LOG  ===
ABORTED - 2 - ssh -i /apps/dw/params/.aws_srvc_etl **IP_ADDRESS **bash /apps/dw/etl/shell_scripts/ec2_script_change_log.sh  \
- [ksh]
/apps/dw/etl/shell_scripts/ec2_script_change_log.sh: line 5:  : command not found
```

Could you please help me to debug?

I am running the above script to get the output. But its failing.
I want ksh command should not fail and run properly inside of other script.

Comment: You should provide your `run_ssh_ec2.sh` and `ec2_script_change_log.sh` scripts, or at least a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of them. Your error message suggests that `ec2_script_change_log.sh` has an empty command in it somewhere but without seeing the script we can't tell you exactly what you did wrong.

Comment: My expectation is you probably have something like `"$MYCMD" <args>`  where you expect MYCMD to be a predefined variable, but it doesn't exist in the runtime of your script.